# How to apply daylight saving shift in data using R?

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I have a dataset with one column showing the data_time of the observations. The problem with this data is that they have not shifted the time on March and November of each year. I want to have all my data in "UTC" time zone, and the lack of time shift is problematic of course. Is there anyway I can automate the correction (manual shift) with R?

The time zone of the observations is "America/Montreal".

Here I uploaded an example for one of the variables and for the year 2020: [csv file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alireza-Amani/my_data/master/2020.csv)

Just to be clear, for instance, on 8th of March 2020, a proper date_time should be like this:

2020-03-08 0:00

2020-03-08 1:00

2020-03-08 3:00

2020-03-08 4:00

...

2020-03-08 23:00

I would be ok if I could manually shift the time on that two days and know a way in R to shift the rest of the date_time column + and - one hour.

Comment: it just came to my mind now, how about removing the wrong date_time column and replacing it with a proper `seq.POSIXt`? This does solve the problem I guess, but still Im interested to know how would one approach this issue with R.

Comment: The `clock` package offers a variety of tools to help with time zones and DST: https://clock.r-lib.org/articles/recipes.html#when-is-the-next-daylight-saving-time-event